# $L_1$ convergence for a product of indicator functions

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables and let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be some set such that $P(X_1\in A)<1$. I have a product of indicator functions
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{N}1\{X_n\in A\}
$$
and am interested in its limit behavior. Specifically, are there conditions on the dependence between the $X_n$, that are weaker than iid, and ensure convergence to zero in $L_1$ norm? That is
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\prod_{n=1}^{N}1\{X_n\in A\}\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{N}X_n\in A\right)=0.
$$

I have already asked a question regarding this issue [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312828/ergodic-sequence-joint-probability-rate-to-zero?noredirect=1#comment780964_312828). I know that ergodicity implies that the product converges to zero almost surely, but in the link Anthony Quas argues that this does not hold in $L_1$ norm.

Any hint or reference is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood Anthony's comment.  When the product converges to zero almost surely, so that $P(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n \in A\}) = 0$, then it certainly converges in $L^1$ as well.  This is just the "continuity from above" property of probability measures and follows immediately from countable additivity.  (Or you could use the dominated convergence theorem.)  I understood Anthony's comment to be saying that you can't always get *exponentially fast* convergence to zero.

Comment: You are right. I guess I stared at this problem for too long, I'll delete this question. Thank you for the reply!